# momentJS default locale is zh-tw and can't seem to overwrite it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm pulling the momentJS library from a CDN in my Angular app:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The default locale is supposed to be English ('en'). But for some reason, the default locale in my app is 'zh-tw'. I see that this used to be an issue (see [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/422) and [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/421)), but it was supposedly fixed.

Even if I set the global locale manually, it is being ignored:

**In my index.html file:**

```
<script>
    moment.locale('en');
</script>
```

**In my Angular controller:**

```
moment.locale('en');
```

The only thing that works right now is if I set the locale on each moment instance:

```
var moment1 = moment(myDate);
moment1.locale('en');
var moment2 = moment(moment1).add(24, 'h');
moment2.locale('en');
```

Comment: I had the same problem and was stumped. Then I redownloaded moment.js (2.10.6 at time of writing) and the default went back to 'en'. I guess whatever version we both had was using the wrong default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Angular, usually what works for me is this

```
.run(["moment", function(moment){
    moment.locale("en");
}]);
```

Comment: Lo and behold, that works. Thank you. I'm confused as to why it's necessary to inject "moment". Why is it not sufficient to load the JS file in index.html? Shouldn't that script be available globally? In any case, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware this question was posted last year but it's worth noting the following for any users coming across the `zh-tw` formatting issue.

This problem cropped up for me today whilst working with the format method. Luckily there is a more permanent fix to this problem within the last few days.

The issue you're having was originally resolved back in 2013 (approximately) and a subsequent update was released. For whatever reason the problem came back in an update sometime before/around update 2.10.3 and has been an issue since. However, on 2 January 2016 they released an update which has subsequently resolved the problem people were having. Updating to `Moment 2.11.0` will resolve the language defaulting to `zh-tw` and revert it back to `en` by default.

Whilst the accepted answer was the fix at the time I recommend you update to the latest version of Moment as from my perspective it was a bit of hack around to resolve your issue, amongst other reasons.

Visit the following link for all the changes in Moment 2.11.0, the issue you'll be interested in is under `ID #2735`.

[Moment 2.11.0 - Changelog](https://gist.github.com/ichernev/6594bc29719dde6b2f66)